# How to make the Kafka Connect BigQuery Sink Connector create one table per event type and not per topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using [confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/) on our Kafka (Avro) events. On some topics, we have more than one event type, e.g., `UserRegistered` and `UserDeleted` are on the topic `domain.user`.

The subjects in our Schema Registry look as follows.

```sh
curl --silent -X GET http://avro-schema-registry.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:8081/subjects | jq .
```

```
[...]
  "domain.user-com.acme.message_schema.domain.user.UserDeleted",
  "domain.user-com.acme.message_schema.domain.user.UserRegistered",
  "domain.user-com.acme.message_schema.type.domain.key.DefaultKey",
[...]
```

My `properties/connector.properties` (I'm using the [quickstart](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/tree/master/kcbq-connector/quickstart) folder.) looks as follows:

```
[...]
topics.regex=domain.*
sanitizeTopics=true
autoCreateTables=true
[...]
```

In BigQuery a table called `domain_user` is created. However, I would like to have two tables, e.g., `domain_user_userregistered` and `domain_user_userdeleted` or similar, because the schemas of these two event types are quite different. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [SchemaNameToTopic](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-transform-common/transformations/SchemaNameToTopic.html) Single Message Transform to do this. By setting the topic name as the schema name this will propagate through to the name given to the created BigQuery table.